# The connected components of a set with empty interior

Tags: general-topology

I have the following question, and I can't seem to get it:

Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $A\subseteq X$ with $\mathring{A}=\emptyset$.
Prove that the connected components of $A$ are the singlton sets.

I think I may be having conceptual issues here.
For $A=\{(0,x):x\in[0,1]\cup[2,3]\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$,  $$\mathring{A}=\bigcup_{\substack{U\subseteq A\\U\text{ open}}}U,$$
but $A$ has no non-empty open subset, so wouldn't $\mathring{A}=\emptyset$. But $\{(0,x):x\in[0,1]\}$ is connected so wouldn't the connected component for $(0,1/2)$, say, contain this set and thus not be singlton?

Does this counter example work?

EDIT: I misread the question, and typed it wrong from memory. The question correctly read, "let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathring{A}=\emptyset,\cdots$". This is simple, as the connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are the intervals.

Comment: The claim is false, the counter example works.

Comment: Thanks, I misread the question from the sheet (see edit). The correctly stated problem is straight forward.

Comment: That's a curious way to write the interior $A^\circ$. I wonder if that's how the Norwegians do it. :)

Comment: It's how my lecture notes and problem sheets are done. I'm still fairly new to LaTeX, so when I type up my solutions, I emulate the notes' styles as accurately as I can to learn different ways of laying things out.

Comment: I'm fairly sure my Lecturer for topology is Greek if that helps.

Comment: @Mario Carneiro: it's standard notation. It's used by Bourbaki.

Comment: @Ori: $\mathbb R$ has only one connected component…

Comment: @Bernard: Yes, that was a slip on my part again. I meant connected subsets.

Comment: @Mario: It’s an ugly notation used by Bourbaki.